# Categorize datetime value to shifts where shift ends on the next day

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a MySQL query for example:

```
select sum(qty) as qty
from myitem
where filedatetime >='2019-08-01 06:30:00'
  and filedatetime < '2019-09-01 18:30:00'
```

My table only have qty and filedatetime columns.

Based on this query is it possible to query out the following conditions:

- if filedatetime is filedatetime >= '2019-08-01 06:30:00' and filedatetime < '2019-08-01 18:30:00' then

  - assign value 'Day' to column shift
  - assign value '2019-08-01' to column shiftDate
- if filedatetime >= '2019-08-01 18:30:00' and filedatetime < '2019-08-02 06:30:00' then

  - assign value 'Night' to column shift
  - assign value '2019-08-01' to column shiftDate

So this how the result will be look like:

```
shiftDate   |   Shift   |   QTY     |
2019-08-01  |   Day     |   10      |
2019-08-01  |   Night   |   12      |
2019-08-02  |   Day     |   11      |
2019-08-02  |   Night   |   15      |
2019-08-11  |   Day     |   11      |
2019-08-11  |   Night   |   18      |
2019-08-12  |   Day     |   13      |
2019-08-12  |   Night   |   19      |
```

Comment: Make it possible to assist you: [mcve]

Comment: Provide some code you've written for this already and stuff you've already tried, and try and clean up the explanation a bit. I've read through it 3 times already and still don't know what you want to know.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the two shifts are exactly 12 hours long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Time()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time) function to extract time (**hh:mm:ss**) portion out of a datetime value. Once we have determined that, we can use [`CASE .. WHEN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) conditional expression, to check whether "Day" or "Night" shift based on your defined conditions. Also, we can use [`Date()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function to extract the date (**YYYY-mm-dd**) portion and add/subtract 1 day accordingly.

We can then `GROUP BY` on these calculated expressions, and calculate sum of the `qty`; no need of using a subquery for further aggregation:

```
SELECT 

  -- Determining day of the shift
  CASE 
     -- When below 06:30:00 then previous day's Night shift
     WHEN TIME(filedatetime) < '06:30:00'
     THEN DATE(filedatetime) - INTERVAL 1 DAY
     -- Else When >= 06:30:00 then current day's shift
     ELSE DATE(filedatetime)
  END AS shiftDate, 

  -- Determining Night / Day
  CASE 
      -- When between 06:30:00 (inclusive) and 18:30:00 then Day
      WHEN TIME(filedatetime) >= '06:30:00' AND TIME(filedatetime) < '18:30:00'
      THEN 'Day'
      ELSE 'Night'
  END AS shift, 

  -- Do aggregation
  SUM(qty) AS qty 
FROM myitem 
WHERE filedatetime >='2019-08-01 06:30:00'
  AND filedatetime < '2019-09-01 18:30:00'
GROUP BY shiftDate, shift
```

Comment: My mistake. This query is runnable. but i not yet check the result it correct or not

Comment: Nice great it working. Thanks. Such query is absolutely out of my mind.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `time` functionality directly:

```
select mi.*,
       (case when cast(filedatetime as time) >= '06:30:00' and
                  cast(filedatetime as time) < '18:30:00'
             then 'day' else 'night'
        end) as shift
from myitem mi;
```

In MySQL, you can also use `time(filedatetime)` function instead of `cast()`.